# How to save in excel 2010+ with NPOI 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, corrupt, npoi

I use NPOI for a long time and it always works but now I need to make it work with .xlsx and at least Microsoft Office 2010. It works but when I try to open the file it says that it's corrupt and I can not repair it. Here's the error I get :

```
Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error.  Load error. Line 1, column 7550.
Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
```

Thanks for the help!

I rty with this sample and I still get the same problem : http://www.leniel.net/2014/02/npoi2.0-excel-2007-xssfworkbook-and-word-2007-xwpfdocument-support.html#sthash.T7qk6CSv.dpbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got in contact with NPOI developer and he told me this:

> it depends
>   the reason may be very different
>   I'm fixing a weird issue caused by SharpZip
>   the zip package may also cause this issue but not on every computer

There's a related issue here: https://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/13046

He updated the code with [***A FIX***](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/commit/e3d7579afc547d033041f701159d799547b8ba06) and looks like the problem went away. I'd suggest you download the code from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), compile it and give it a try.

Comment: loved your posts on NPOI.  They go me started in no time.  Great work.

Comment: @David Robbins: really glad it's being helpful. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @LenielMacaferi it did solve my issue, they should push this to nuget!

Comment: @VinnyG yep... agree. We should make this process a faster one! I'll get in contact with Tony and see what we can do.

Comment: This bug exists in current nuget version : 2.0.6